# How do I make a high score in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#, gui

I want to make a GUI box displaying a high score, but I have no idea how to do it. How do I make a high score in Unity?

Here is what I have done so far:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Highscore : Tap
{
    public static int HighScore;

    void Update() 
    {
        if (HighScore > counter)
        {
            HighScore = counter;
            HighScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Highscore", HighScore);
            PlayerPrefs.Save();
        }
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        GUIStyle customButton = new GUIStyle("button");
        customButton.fontSize = 75;
        GUI.Box(new Rect(550, 200, 500, 90), "Highscore:" + HighScore, customButton);
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll get more control and flexibility by using the new UI system introduced in 4.6, rather than drawing everything through code in an OnGUI method. Have you worked through any of the tutorials for these UI elements?

Comment: Are you asking how to display text on screen in Unity?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I can't directly help with the OnGUI method as I haven't used it directly, though I can tell you that the unity UI system is excellent at such tasks and I have made such things successfully in the past using a canvas, a text field and code that alters the value in the text field dynamically. I don't know how much better or easier this would be in comparison to OnGUI, though building a canvas and a text field only take literally 30 seconds to do simply by going to 'Create > UI > Canvas' and then 'Create > UI > Text' from the hierarchy pane within Unity.

If you haven't used the Unity UI system before, the Canvas is essentially the board you can pin things to for viewing by the user. The weird thing is that by default it appears absolutely massive in your scene view, and the text field will also appear quite large in comparison to your scene. This is normal, and what will happen when you play the game is that this canvas will resize to the player's screen size and display over the top of whatever is happening. If you parent the text field to the canvas (in the hierarchy pane just drag the text field onto the canvas, it should then parent to the canvas), the text field will appear wherever you place it in front of anything else in view.

In your code there's a few ways you can then set the high score value to your field, but a simple and flexible way (if you change things later) is creating an empty variable then setting it to be your high score in a similar fashion as below:

```
public UnityEngine.UI.Text ScoreToUpdate;

void Update (){
    ScoreToUpdate.text = HighScore; // Whatever variable you use to store/pass your high score after the = here
}
```

The final step is then just to attach the script to the canvas, then with the canvas selected drag the text object from your hierarchy into the 'ScoreToUpdate' field of the script on the canvas object, then that should be it. Your high score should then be displayed on screen at all times in the place you set it.

Apologies if some of these things aren't perfect - i'm a relative noob to unity and programming in general, and i'm away from my unity dev pc to check this fully. This should be fairly close to what you need if it's not exact though.

Comment: I think your ScoreToUpdate variable should be of type UnityEngine.UI.Text instead, so you can get at the text property without a GetComponent call first.

Comment: Ah, that's a good point. Edited to reflect this suggestion. Thanks